# Why do PostgreSQL indexes stop being used after a while

Tags: sql, postgresql

Postgres version: 11.2

I've got a table with about 40M rows.

The query I'm doing on it(more fields exist in the query, it's the `where` clause that counts):

```sql
select id,name from my_table where
action_performed = true AND
should_still_perform_action = false AND
action_performed_at <= '2021-09-05 00:00:00.000'
LIMIT 100;
```

The date is just something I picked for this example.

There's an index on the table, specifically for this query:

```sql
CREATE INDEX my_index ON my_table USING
 btree (action_performed, should_still_perform_action, action_performed_at desc)
 where should_still_perform_action=false and action_performed=true;
```

Upon creation, this works fine for a few weeks. Tests with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` show the index being used.

And then it stops and start using a sequential scan.

Dropping and re-creating the index fixes this. The index is used again for a few weeks.

And the pattern repeats and never stops.

There's a daily `vacuum analyze` that runs on the database. Isn't that enough?

I've tried looking into this, but I just don't get why it's happening. Especially the fact that re-creating the index fixes it... but only for a while...

What are the mechanics at play here, what is the detail I'm missing out on?

EDIT:

- Index statement was included in the original.

```
CREATE INDEX my_index ON my_table USING
 btree (action_performed, should_still_perform_action, action_performed_at desc)
 where should_still_perform_action=false and action_performed=true;
```

Unless you want me to provide every single index on the table?

- Doing an `ANALYZE TABLE mytable` changes nothing.
- About the timestamp in the WHERE clauses:

Performing this:

```
select count(*) from mytable where action_performed = TRUE AND should_still_perform_action = FALSE;
```

Returns 75490 rows, at time of writing.

Adding the timestamp filter returns 60638 rows, at time of writing.

So that's just over 80% included.

The total amount of rows in the entire table is just over 40 million.

Surprisingly, those two count queries **do** use the index in question. But when I add some fields, instead of doing a count, it becomes a seq scan.

- I know there's a vacuum analyze running, I set it up myself and it appears in the logs every night, and I see the amount of dead rows dropping nightly on monitoring software. So yes, the command `vacuum analyze;` is executed nightly.

After manual tests now, I'm finding that even recreating the index isn't enough anymore.

Here's the result of the query 3 times before recreating the index and 3 times after:

```sql
                                                                     QUERY PLAN                                                                      
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.00..680.43 rows=100 width=3588) (actual time=327.796..76338.649 rows=100 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared read=1036315 dirtied=3246 written=3201
   ->  Seq Scan on mytable (cost=0.00..4138873.15 rows=6082746 width=3588) (actual time=327.793..76337.977 rows=100 loops=1)
         Filter: (action_performed AND (NOT should_still_perform_action) AND (action_performed_at <= '2021-09-05 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 15016717
         Buffers: shared read=1036315 dirtied=3246 written=3201
 Planning Time: 323.974 ms
 Execution Time: 76339.454 ms
(8 rows)

Time: 77045.332 ms (01:17.045)

                                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                                     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.00..680.68 rows=100 width=3596) (actual time=0.062..19434.770 rows=100 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=5 read=270784 dirtied=3613 written=3522
   ->  Seq Scan on mytable (cost=0.00..4139053.70 rows=6080733 width=3596) (actual time=0.060..19433.989 rows=100 loops=1)
         Filter: (action_performed AND (NOT should_still_perform_action) AND (action_performed_at <= '2021-09-05 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 3664941
         Buffers: shared hit=5 read=270784 dirtied=3613 written=3522
 Planning Time: 0.634 ms
 Execution Time: 19435.205 ms
(8 rows)

Time: 19437.005 ms (00:19.437)

                                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                                    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.00..680.68 rows=100 width=3596) (actual time=0.049..2752.928 rows=100 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=11 read=37642 dirtied=376 written=371
   ->  Seq Scan on mytable (cost=0.00..4139053.70 rows=6080733 width=3596) (actual time=0.047..2752.339 rows=100 loops=1)
         Filter: (action_performed AND (NOT should_still_perform_action) AND (action_performed_at <= '2021-09-05 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 484310
         Buffers: shared hit=11 read=37642 dirtied=376 written=371
 Planning Time: 4.584 ms
 Execution Time: 2753.294 ms
(8 rows)
```

After index re-create and vacuum analyze:

```sql
                                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                                    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.00..695.85 rows=100 width=3605) (actual time=17.365..195.390 rows=100 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared read=2066
   ->  Seq Scan on mytable (cost=0.00..4139104.05 rows=5948306 width=3605) (actual time=17.363..195.200 rows=100 loops=1)
         Filter: (action_performed AND (NOT should_still_perform_action) AND (action_performed_at <= '2021-09-05 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 28521
         Buffers: shared read=2066
 Planning Time: 144.511 ms
 Execution Time: 195.779 ms
(8 rows)

Time: 403.420 ms


                                                                   QUERY PLAN                                                                    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.00..695.85 rows=100 width=3605) (actual time=0.020..754.859 rows=100 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=2 read=10486
   ->  Seq Scan on mytable (cost=0.00..4139104.05 rows=5948306 width=3605) (actual time=0.018..754.567 rows=100 loops=1)
         Filter: (action_performed AND (NOT should_still_perform_action) AND (action_performed_at <= '2021-09-05 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 147815
         Buffers: shared hit=2 read=10486
 Planning Time: 0.489 ms
 Execution Time: 755.082 ms
(8 rows)

Time: 756.770 ms


                                                                    QUERY PLAN                                                                    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.00..695.85 rows=100 width=3605) (actual time=0.096..8309.539 rows=100 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=8 read=115650
   ->  Seq Scan on mytable (cost=0.00..4139104.05 rows=5948306 width=3605) (actual time=0.094..8308.789 rows=100 loops=1)
         Filter: (action_performed AND (NOT should_still_perform_action) AND (action_performed_at <= '2021-09-05 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 1550214
         Buffers: shared hit=8 read=115650
 Planning Time: 1.119 ms
 Execution Time: 8309.966 ms
(8 rows)

Time: 8312.732 ms (00:08.313)
```

I hope this is all the information needed.

EDIT2: Disabling seqscan causes the index to get used, though obviously you can't do that in production.

Comment: LIMIT without ORDER BY doesn't make much sense. Your partial index could be simply created on the single column `action_performed_at`, the other two can only have the values should_still_perform_action=false and action_performed=true to be included in the index and must also be included with the same values in a WHERE clause for the index to be used. Have you checked if the table really gets analyzed daily? What if you execute an `ANALYZE TABLE my_table` instead of recreating the index?

Comment: You just think there is s vacuum running on it everyday, or you know there is because you see the count of completed vacs going up by one each day?  What is the size of the index before and after recreating it?

Comment: `action_performed_at <= '2021-09-05 00:00:00.000'` <<-- what fraction of the rows will be selected/excluded by this condition?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add both [execution plans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) (the slow and fast) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I've updated the question with the details everyone has asked for. I've petitioned for it to be opened again, but nothing so far.

Comment: The index my_index is never used. You have in all your query plans a sequential scan. Have you tried adding an ORDER BY to your query and changing the index?

Comment: @Steeeve It never being used is exactly what I'm researching. Turning seqscan off causes it to get used. I tried using "order by" but no effect there. I don't see how I could change the index for that.

Comment: @KoenDG You have stated that the index is used and after a while not anymore. The number of rows removed by the filter are as low as `Rows Removed by Filter: 28521` from a total of `rows=5948306`. There is no sense using an index in that case, the sequential scan is probably more efficient. Also, the number of rows are varying in a large range but are still very small in relation to the total number of rows.

Comment: @Steeeve So I guess I'm not thinking about the problem correctly then? My main issue here is that sometimes the query will take 3 minutes, sometimes it will take 8 seconds. The amount of filtered rows I've seen go up to 1.5 million. I've seen buffers read 8GB of data, but also 300MB of data. It's wildly inconsistent, for a dataset(the boolean conditions) that never really goes above 100K rows. And I'm trying to get it more consistent.

Comment: @KoenDG Without using an ORDER BY you can't get consistent values with LIMIT. The rows will be fetched in an undefined order. How many rows are cached (in the buffers) depends on the load. If you execute the query the first time there will be probably nothing buffered. Executing it a second time immediately after the first run there is a good chance to get many rows from the buffers.

Comment: I would try a partial index on the single column action_performed_at and an order by action_performed_at.

Comment: @Steeeve Right. I'll have to re-think the entire way this data is fetched and handled, then. Because the timestamp condition is really only there to say "only process entries older than today" or the given timestamp, in general. The order in which they are returned is of no practical importance, since the goal is to perform processing on any entry that has not yet been processed. The LIMIT was introduced to stop the application doing so from hanging, as there's potentially network activity as part of the processing and it might take a while if suddenly 100K+ items are returned.

Comment: @Steeeve Thanks for taking the time to talk about this btw.

Comment: Wouldn't be it then better to remove LIMIT and simply not fetch all the results?

Comment: I just googled that and I had never before heard of FETCH. Though from what I read, it should be functionally equivalent? Though the documentation only mentions LIMIT being taken into account for the query planner, I wonder if that's an oversight in the documentation, or veritably FETCH doesn't get used by the query planner? I'll be testing this out tomorrow.

Comment: @KoenDG I'm not a PSQL pro, there are here many far more advanced users than me. Maybe you should reword the question in something 'like how to optimize this query' because the title is wrong. Or perhaps a completely new question, with the table definition, query and query plan. Normally I see here many really good answers when it comes to optimizations. Let me know if you open a new question, I would upvote it, because I'm also interested.

Comment: @Steeeve I made that new question, not sure if pings from there will notifiy if a user hasn't made a comment yet, so here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69176081/postgresql-how-to-improve-this-query-index?noredirect=1#comment122266826_69176081